# How did the First Order build Starkiller base so quickly?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

*In Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, we see that the First Order has constructed a massive superweapon called the Starkiller, very similar to the two previous Death Stars, though much more powerful, and much, MUCH larger, as observed when the members of the Resistance are comparing it in size to the original Death Star.

In addition, the Starkiller is built *into the planet it's on!!!*

The first question that comes to mind is how the First Order even accomplished this amazing feat.  But the real question is:

**How did the First Order build Starkiller base so quickly?**

Since *The Force Awakens* happens just about 30 years after *The Return of the Jedi*, when there is no hint of the Starkiller even existing, and considering that the original, much smaller Death Star took over *twenty years* to construct, how is this even possible?

Comment: Man, can you imagine how long it would take IRL to build something that big...

Comment: They used more cowbell

Comment: [How did they dig the big trench in Star Killer Base?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114600/how-did-they-dig-the-big-trench-in-star-killer-base)

Comment: @xdhmoore - With limitless supplies, droid workers and gravity control? Probably a lot less time than you'd think.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They only had to build the super weapon part of star-killer base, all of the superstructure was already there in the form of the planet. 
This would have significantly reduced the time required to build it.

Secondly the knowledge of building 2 previous super weapons would have made the creation of a third quicker and easier.

Yes it took 20 years from concept to creation of the first death star (though only a portion of this would be actual building time) but the second death star took a fraction of the time (assuming it started construction after the destruction of the first)

Comment: And there is also a massive benefit in having an inhabitable planet to work on rather than trying to move stuff around in space. Even though repulsorlifts, sublights, and hyperdrives exist and are 'normal', they all cost fuel. Building something into the planet would mean there is LESS to construct, not having to worry about things like engines and foundations, because they're part of the planet already.

Comment: But it was a completely different technology where it drew energy from the nearby sun. The size is a massive 5x's that of the Death Star. Hollowing out a massive planet such as this would take a centuries if not a millennia at best to complete.

Comment: @user64400 Yes, I think people are ignoring the fact that the planet was hallowed out and all this equipment was built around and into it. By the square cube law, starkiller base easily was a much more massive project than either Death Star. Not to mention that the First Order has no where near the resources or manpower that the Empire at its height had. I think there comes a time where it must be admitted that Starkiller base makes no sense whatsoever. But hey, it's Star Wars.

Comment: I assure you, there was nothing hallowed about that planet. That said, what makes you think it was hollow?

Comment: @T.J.L. No one said anything about it being hollow

Comment: You are absolutely correct, nobody said "hollow" before I did. However, @DBPriGuy did say it was "hallowed out," hence my gently mocking comment.

Comment: why would "knowledge of building 2 previous super weapons" help. The 1st two used Kyber crystals as "fuel" & focused energy while StarKiller based "sucked" in the nearby star and spat it out

Comment: @Naib experience in managing vast projects with a large workforce is nothing to be sniffed at.

Comment: @T.J.L. Oops thought it was comment on the answer and didn't see that in the comments despite looking twice (dangers of reading late at night)

Answer (score 7):

We learn in [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know, Updated and Expanded](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know,_Updated_and_Expanded) that the planet was already home to significant Empire mining operations before the First Order took over, dating back to 20BBY

[image]

Presumably the Starkiller Base was an extension of *existing facilities* that were already in place (for 50+ years), rather than something started from scratch by the First Order.

Comment: So essentially "We already have a huge mineshaft, it's the perfect place to mount our megalaser". Makes more sense than building a Death Moon from scratch tbh.

Comment: This was later depicted visually in _Jedi: Fallen Order_: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ilum#Under_the_Empire