# How did they dig the big trench in Star Killer Base?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Star Killer Base has an extremely deep, long, and wide trench. If the base were the size of Earth, I would guess the trench to be twelve thousand miles long, 1,500 miles wide, and 1,500 miles deep.  We get the sense that the base was constructed from a pre-existing planet. **what technologies and methods did they use to dig a trench of that massive size?**

[image]

Comment: They got a big digger

Comment: A whole lotta stormtroopers, and a whole lotta shovels.

Comment: I'm going with "lasers".

Comment: @Richard By my guess, they would have to either vaporize or remove **27 billion cubic miles of ore and soil** to make a trench of that scale. The machine to do that might need to be a retrofitted death star.

Comment: @codemed - Lasers *and tractor beams*.

Comment: Why do you assume they dug it?  Lots of alternatives for a formation like that.

Comment: That's assuming it they dug it... http://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/56839826.jpg

Comment: @Vogie Did you mean Bart?  http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=CtVteemLin4

Comment: One spoonful at a time.

Comment: @Richard - Sharks. With lasers on their heads

Comment: @CodeMed - ever heard of "Centerpoint Station"? Hyperspace tractor beam. Doubles as super-weapon

Comment: Related: [Was this location built or mined out?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111481/was-this-location-built-or-mined-out)

Comment: A better question is: why did they dig the trench? It seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Mohair I think the answer to that is that they wanted a larger, overblown version of the tunnels the X-Wings flew through in the original 1976 film. Cosmetic out of universe explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: They used giant vacuums.

**World Devastator**

[image]

[image]

> ... World Devastators could use a targeted world's material resources for the Empire's benefit. A Devastator's primary tactic was to land on the surface of a planet. There, its mighty **tractor beam projectors would literally tear the planet beneath it apart**, thus making them "planet killers." Thus, the World Devastators functioned similar to the Star Forge, which also harvested materials from a nearby astronomical object.
>
> The deconstruction of the planet and its resources would then be used for both fuel for the Devastator and for its massive foundries which churned out starships, starfighters, and droids which would be sent into battle straight from the assembly line. **The internal factories could create anything** from a starfighter or speeder to a medium-sized cruiser, given enough resources. –[wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/World_Devastator)

Comment: The real question is, where's all the slag piles?

Comment: Thank you and +1 for going where no one had gone before in terms of knowing the answer to this.

Comment: @CodeMed - After you've read Zhan's novels, check out the *Dark Empire* comic. That's where I first heard of them. IMO, *those* are episodes 7~10; TFA is episode 11+, as we seem to have also skipped the events of the Jedi Academy trilogy. Also, their names have been changed to protect the non-innocent? Their children's names are Jacen, Jaina and Anakin.

Comment: Do these exist in the current canon?

Comment: @chepner - This is now 'Legends' canon. [How is canonicity of derivative works determined for Star Wars?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars)

Comment: Thanks; that's what I meant to ask, but phrased poorly (i.e., is it legends or retained as part of the new canon).

Comment: @chepner - You'd have to ask [Leland Chee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Leland_Chee). Or you could, you know, think whatever you want (I hate this 'canon' non-sense - no one else gets to decide for me what has happened in a galaxy far, far away).

Comment: @Mazura - Then perhaps it would be better to phrase it, "are these _movie_ cannon"?  Because (while we don't know for sure about these) Jacen, Jaina, and Anakin, who appear in the Dark Empire comics, are not part of the new movie canon.