# Can a tractor beam suck up an entire city like New York?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Would a tractor beam in Star Wars have the power to suck up a major city like New York or Singapore? Example of what I think a tractor beam would do to Singapore:

[image]

<sub>Picture courtesy of *Independence Day: Resurgence*</sub>

Have tractor beams ever been used in Star Wars to destroy things at all?

Comment: Where are these pictures from?

Comment: @Jonah *[Independence Day: Resurgence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nh5ZKo8730k)*. (from Google images)

Comment: @armadillo - So does that mean that this is asking a question about *Star Wars* in terms of the fictional technology in another work?

Comment: It's asking if tractor beams have ever been used in SW to destroy things.

Comment: That's right Mazura. If not seen destroying stuff, then can it's power be enough to do the damage to the cities like above?

Comment: Either canon, legends or both. Any of them would be great. And hopefully, someone can answer this question soon.

Comment: Damn, before I saw the Star Wars tag I was going to cite the destruction of Federation outposts along the Romulan Neutral Zone by the Borg (presumably using tractor beams). Wrong franchise!

Comment: IMO, the title calls for an ancillary ST answer (just how *presumably* was it? @ApproachingDarknessFish)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, although it (probably) won't be in one piece!
In the Legends' Dark Empire comic book series (and mentioned elsewhere in Legends EU), the Empire built the [World Devastators](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/World_Devastator):

> A Devastator's primary tactic was to land on the surface of a planet. There, its mighty tractor beam projectors would literally tear the planet beneath it apart, thus making them "planet killers."

The most obvious example of this comes when a group of the 3km machines were tasked to attack Mon Cal:
[image: World Devastators attack Mon Cal]

... although sometimes they just needed a light snack, and munched on Star Destroyers:

[image: Emancipator for Lunch]

Comment: See also, [How did they dig the big trench in Star Killer Base?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114600/how-did-they-dig-the-big-trench-in-star-killer-base)